# How to play two sounds simultaneously using Media Foundation

Tags: c++, c, ms-media-foundation

I tried to play multiple sounds simultaneously using Media Foundation. I created multiple Media Sessions and loaded multiple IMFMediaSources. But the problem is that IMFMediaSource can't be used again during playback. Is there any better way to allow simultaneous playback? Multiple audio or repeat one of them?

Comment: You may wish to consider using [XAudio2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/xaudio2/xaudio2-introduction) instead. Media foundation is meant for high quality playback usually by music or video players.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I also realized the problem, I am trying some, thank you for taking the time to consider my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you elaborate a bit more ?

For example, you can restart a IMFMediaSource to reapeat it :

[IMFMediaSource::Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-imfmediasource-start) :

> Starts, seeks, or restarts the media source by specifying where to start playback.

Or you can simply stop the source and then start again :

[IMFMediaSource::Stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-imfmediasource-stop)

> When a media source is stopped, its current position reverts to zero. After that, if the Start method is called with VT_EMPTY for the starting position, playback starts from the beginning of the presentation.

PS : I agree with Mgetz, if you only play simple wav files, XAudio2 is an option. Tell us your audio file format.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to consider my question. I realized that my program might use XAudio2 to have a more suitable solution. As Mgetz said, I didn't see what I needed when I tried to read the official Media Foundation documentation. Something. It may not be suitable for my needs. I am now trying to solve my problem with XAudio2.